# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle

CASE WHEN WEIGHT >0 THEN ROUND((WEIGHT/ POWER((HEIGHT/100),2)),3)ELSE '' END

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

How to convert weight column to number

need to convert wight column to char

tried to_char still same error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your THEN clause returns Number and ELSE returns ''. This is conficting. Values returned by CASE expression must be of the same datatype.If you try it without ELSE (below) then, if the condition is not satisfied, you'll get Null as a result and null could be managed (if needed) either by Nvl() or Coalesce() functions or any other way:

```sql
CASE WHEN WEIGHT > 0 THEN ROUND((WEIGHT/ POWER((HEIGHT/100),2)),3) END
```

If your WEIGHT column is character convert it using [To_Number() function.](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php)